# The index on JSON_EXTRACT function doesn't returns the data

Tags: mysql, json

my problem is when i try take a data with mysql function JSON_EXTRACT, the thing is i do with index [0] and everything works fine, but when i ask for the next one [1], return null. I've tried with no index to know how search and that returned all my json data, and when i tried to take an indexed position over 0 position, doesn't returns any data, just null. Here is my sample code:

```
set @example = '{"product":{
                            "id_product":1, 
                            "quantity":1
                           },
                 "product":{
                            "id_product":3, 
                            "quantity":4
                            },
                 "product":{
                            "id_product":5, 
                            "quantity":2
                            }
                 }';

select JSON_EXTRACT(@example, '$.product[0].id_product'); -- Returns '1'
select JSON_EXTRACT(@example, '$.product[1].id_product'); -- Returns null, should be '3'
```

I would like to know how exactly works if is not really to use like this.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Last duplicate key wins**.

> [11.6 The JSON Data Type :: Normalization, Merging, and Autowrapping of JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)
>
> ...
>
> This "last duplicate key wins" behavior is suggested by RFC 7159 and is implemented by most JavaScript
>   parsers.
>
> ...
>
> In versions of MySQL prior to 8.0.3, members with keys that duplicated a key found earlier in the document were discarded.
>
> ...

**Example:**

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.15    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @`example` := '{
    '>   "product": {
    '>     "id_product": 1,
    '>     "quantity": 1
    '>   },
    '>   "product": {
    '>     "id_product": 3,
    '>     "quantity": 4
    '>   },
    '>   "product": {
    '>     "id_product": 5,
    '>     "quantity": 2
    '>   }
    '> }';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_VALID(@`example`);
+------------------------+
| JSON_VALID(@`example`) |
+------------------------+
|                      1 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_LENGTH(@`example`);
+-------------------------+
| JSON_LENGTH(@`example`) |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$.product');
+---------------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$.product') |
+---------------------------------------+
| {"quantity": 2, "id_product": 5}      |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Some options**

**Option 0**:

```sql
mysql> SET @`example` := '{
    '>   "product_0": {
    '>     "id_product": 1,
    '>     "quantity": 1
    '>   },
    '>   "product_1": {
    '>     "id_product": 3,
    '>     "quantity": 4
    '>   },
    '>   "product_2": {
    '>     "id_product": 5,
    '>     "quantity": 2
    '>   }
    '> }';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_VALID(@`example`);
+------------------------+
| JSON_VALID(@`example`) |
+------------------------+
|                      1 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_LENGTH(@`example`);
+-------------------------+
| JSON_LENGTH(@`example`) |
+-------------------------+
|                       3 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$.product_0.id_product'),
    ->   JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$.product_1.id_product'),
    ->   JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$.product_2.id_product')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$.product_0.id_product'): 1
JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$.product_1.id_product'): 3
JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$.product_2.id_product'): 5
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Option 1**:

```sql
mysql> SET @`example` := '[
    '> {
    '>   "product": {
    '>     "id_product": 1,
    '>     "quantity": 1
    '>   }
    '> },
    '> {
    '>   "product": {
    '>     "id_product": 3,
    '>     "quantity": 4
    '>   }
    '> },
    '> {
    '>   "product": {
    '>     "id_product": 5,
    '>     "quantity": 2
    '>   }
    '> }]';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_VALID(@`example`);
+------------------------+
| JSON_VALID(@`example`) |
+------------------------+
|                      1 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_LENGTH(@`example`);
+-------------------------+
| JSON_LENGTH(@`example`) |
+-------------------------+
|                       3 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$[0].product.id_product'),
    ->   JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$[1].product.id_product'),
    ->   JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$[2].product.id_product')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$[0].product.id_product'): 1
JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$[1].product.id_product'): 3
JSON_EXTRACT(@`example`, '$[2].product.id_product'): 5
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Great, i guess although using mysql version 5.7 (what i’m using) supporting json, doesn’t work properly and a better way to get that is using like you the 8.0.

Comment: @RamonB.C.: In MySQL 5.7, both options work without problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0b811e4ae55ef15d7bae00312c7748db).